# Scaling images with Apache Commons Imaging

Tags: java, scale, apache-commons-imaging

I would like a high-quality way to scale images, in particular JPEG images, using Java. I looked into this extensively around 2007, and at the time JAI had problems that would produce black borders in some scaled images.

Back then I finally settled on a technique of using `Image.getScaledInstance()` and writing to a `BufferedImage` with `Graphics2D` rendering hints, modified from [a technique described by Perry Nguyen](http://www.hanhuy.com/pfn/java-image-thumbnail-comparison). This approach was slower, but produced images virtually identical in quality to JAI subsample average, but without the incorrect borders.

In revisiting this I did some quick research, but I don't see that there is any better way to do this than there was almost 15 years ago. However I did find [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/), a new project that [claims](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/whyimaging.html) to only use Java, so it promising. Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation on scaling images.

Does Apache Common Imaging handle high-quality scaling of images? If so, where can I find documentation?

Comment: @MichaelEaster, that looked interesting until I saw that it was no longer maintained, and moreover the project-related site (see the README) has been abandoned and hijacked (see the issues) and seem to be trying to spread viruses. I realize that doesn't directly affect the code in GitHub, but it doesn't give me confidence in the project being maintained and stable.

Comment: Ah, apologies... I didn't study the current state very well. I've removed my original comment (to remove the link), but for others: I had recommended "imgscalr". But it sounds like it should be *avoided*.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at Patrick Favre's [density-converter](https://github.com/patrickfav/density-converter) library.

It is mainly a command line and GUI image processing tool designed for mobile (Android, iOS) systems.

But even in the case you are looking for a way to integrate it with your code, please review the scaling mechanism implementation performed in the [ImageHandler](https://github.com/patrickfav/density-converter/blob/master/src/main/java/at/favre/tools/dconvert/converters/scaling/ImageHandler.java) class and the different algorithms defined in the package [`at.favre.tools.dconvert.converters.scaling`](https://github.com/patrickfav/density-converter/tree/master/src/main/java/at/favre/tools/dconvert/converters/scaling), I think it could be helpful.